# What are the steps for building a no till vegetable garden, and how late can I start it?

Tags: vegetables, grass

I'm looking at putting my garden along a creek bed in a part that doesn't flood, and was wondering how late I can start it, and if I need to do anything special other than planting the seeds.

Comment: roller crimper: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aiocr_icrfw